# Waiting for a multi-step connection process to complete with Netty

Tags: netty

Forgive me if I fell asleep during Netty 101, but I'm wondering if there's a "right" way to wait for a multi-step connection process to complete with Netty. Let's say I have an application where the process goes something like this:

1. Open the actual connection.
2. Perform a TLS handshake.
3. Do some application-level handshaking to confirm that both the client and server are speaking FancyProtocol 2.8 (or whatever).

When I call `Bootstrap#connect()`, I'm given a `ChannelFuture`. My understanding is that the `ChannelFuture` will succeed as soon as step 1—just opening the connection—is complete, but we'll still need to wait for steps 2 and 3 by some means.

What I've done in the past is to create a secondary "everything is done" `Promise`, and notify that promise as soon as step 3 completes (or if anything fails in the interim). That works well enough, but has the feeling of doing things the hard way when Netty might already have a mechanism in place for dealing with this situation.

So that, I suppose, is my question: *is* there a better way to wait for a multi-step connection process to complete?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Application level handshaking belongs to the application level handler, in your netty handler it's easy to catch the "connect" event with a the channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext) method in a handler.

An example:

```
public class ApplicationLogicHandler extends ChannelInboundHandler {
    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        super.channelActive(ctx);
        ctx.writeAndFlush(new MyApplicationLogicPacket());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think we have the actual application-level handshaking well under control.

My question is more about letting callers outside of the pipeline know that the application-level handshaking has completed. Maybe put a little too specifically: is there a good way to defer, for example, completion of the connection promise until the application-level handshaking is done?